# Setting up math / complex typography in contentful + gatsby

Tags: latex, gatsby, richtext, contentful, katex

As the title says how would you go about doing this? I'm new to both and I know there is the `gatsby-katex-plugin` but in most CMS' I could add a plugin to the richc text editor to write latex that's rendered there as well.

In contentful is this equivalent to writing the latex, adding the katex package, and then seeing it rendered in the page preview?

Just confused about how all the pieces wokr together and how I'd actually go bout writing complex typography into contentfuls fields